# use npm with different configuration than package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-install

I have a complex production environment driven by package.json.

**The problem:**
I wish to install locally some additional packages, keep an eye on the list and versions of them.

**Solution (how to get there):**
point *npm* to use another config file, excluded from git, which would keep my private dependencies. Use the file to add packages to local *node_modules* with *npm install*. So actually all I need is to change configuration context of npm.

I have no clue how to point npm to use a different config (something like *gulp -gulpfile*).

**Update from comments** The dev-dependencies is not the way to go. I use stuff 90% of other developers do not need to get installed in their node_modules (in fact I could **break** their environment in a strange way updating dev-dependencies in git-shared core project-wide *package.json*).

Comment: Quick doubt - do you want to do this to keep the local packages private? Or to prevent them from being installed in production?

Comment: To keep them private. I test a lot of things related to tool-chain, I need to check a package, use it with my custom gulpfile against the actual app and provide a feedback. It may, or may not eventually go to production and to the packages.json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should know that what you are trying to is not only weird, but also against a lot of good practices and patterns in NodeJS.

Nevertheless, it's possible and if it's done right will almost never cause any trouble to you, or other developers in different platforms.

You can use something a little inspired on the [Meteor](http://meteor.com) build flow. Let's break your project conceptually into two different parts:

- **Base:** Handles project initialization.
- **Internal** The original project.

Project structure:

```
- build.js (base build script)
- package.json (base package)
- internal/
  - package.template.json (project package template)
  - app.js (your actual project files)
  - [...]  (your actual project files)
```

The starting point is create a `package.json` file to the **Base**, in the root of the project. This package will hold only the dependencies to build the package file of the **Internal** project. I strongly advise you to use something like [Mozilla's Convict](https://github.com/mozilla/node-convict) to ensure the configurations are done correctly using ENVs. The goal here is to write another `package.json` file at runtime.

Let's also assume in the your environment there's an Environment Variable `USE_WEIRD_MODULES="true"`. You can use this fact in the **Base** project to define which modules you are going to install using the **build.js** file. You can read it and edit in runtime. When it's ready,  save it as `internal/package.json`. Then, run `npm install` inside the `internal/` directory.

**build.js**

```
let pkg = require('./package.template.json');    

if(process.env.USE_WEIRD_MODULES) {

    // Install your weird packages        
    pkg.dependencies.some_dev_package = '^v0.2.2';
    pkg.dependencies.another_dev_package = '^v0.2.2';


}

// Don't forget to save the package.json in the end
fs.writeFileSync('./internal/package.json', JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2), 'utf8');
```

Don't forget to put the `internal/package.json` file in your repository ignore file (ex: gitignore).

To minimize the impact of this brute changes in the project, you can define in the main `package.json` all the building routine in the `postinstall` script. It will allow a simple `npm install` in the root of the project handle all this steps internally.

Something like this:

**package.json**

```
{
  [...]
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node build.js && cd internal/ && npm install",
    "start": "node internal/app.js"
  }
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`npm` already offers a built in feature to handle exactly this requirement. To have different dependencies in your development environment and in production, you can save your dependencies into package.json in two different ways.

1. You can save it as a normal dependency (available in development and production) using the `save` flag. Ex:

   ```
   npm install <package-name> --save`
   ```
2. You can save it as a development dependency (available only in development and not in production) using the `save-dev` flag. Ex:

   ```
   npm install <package-name> --save-dev
   ```

When you run npm install on the server, if the NODE_ENV is set to production, it will not install the dev dependencies.

More on it here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install. There are additional concepts like optional dependencies etc. which you can also use.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the solution: I DO NOT want to share dependencies with the rest of my team via git, I do not need to change their node_modules with packages only I need and use. They do not need to even know anyone is playing with the toolchain or is adding something to it (90% of them do not use the stuff I do, altough all of them depend on development dependencies in package.json)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dev dependencies` instead of using seprate files.

install package using `npm install packageName --dev` the package will go in `devDependencies` of `package.json` eg

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "~3.2.0",
    "supertest": "~1.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "nodemon": "~1.8.1"
  }
```

so when you  `npm install` in dev environment all dependencies will be installed but in production dev dependencies will be ignored

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own realisation.

You need to write package.json builder that can generate **package.json** where dependencies will be only **needed**

**USAGE**

```
node package.json.builder.js prod+test
npm install
```

Here will be created package.json file with dependencies that described in **package.dependencies.js**.

**REALISATION**

1.Add package.json to .gitignore

2.Create file **package.json.builder.js** will create package.json file

```
let fs = require('fs');
let pkgDep = require('./package.dependencies.js');

let pkgTemplete = fs.readFileSync('./package.json.hbs', "utf8");
let obj = {}, dep = [];

if (process.argv[2]) {
  let array = process.argv[2].split('+');

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!pkgDep[array[i] + 'Dependencies']) {
      console.error(array[i] + 'Dependencies' + ' not found in package.dependencies.js');
    } else {
      dep.push(array[i] + 'Dependencies');
    }

Object.assign(obj, pkgDep[array[i] + 'Dependencies'] || {});
  }
}

pkgTemplete = pkgTemplete.replace('{{dependencies}}', JSON.stringify(obj));

fs.writeFileSync('./package.json', pkgTemplete);
console.log('package.json created with ' + dep.join('+'));
```

3.Create **package.json.hbs** (package.json without dependencies)

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {{dependencies}},
  "scripts": {
  }
}
```

4.Create file **package.dependencies.js** object that contains only list of packages and its versions

```
module.exports = {
  prodDependencies: {
    "babel-core": "6.26.0"
  },
  devDependencies: {
    "core-js": "2.5.5"
  },
  testDependencies: {
    "jest": "23.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am little late to the party but this will help someone. You can check following package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/penv

it will allow you to create environment files which can be used in multiple environments.