# Read environment variables in the package.json file

Tags: reactjs

I have currently hardcoded the proxy in the `package.json`:

```
{
    "proxy": "http://server.side"
}
```

Is there a way to import this proxy from `.env` file like for example:

```
{
    "proxy": "process.env.PROXY"
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624054/setting-process-env-var-in-package-json?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting process.env var in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624054/setting-process-env-var-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use system call from a json, maybe use a package json builder look [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056788/use-npm-with-different-configuration-than-package-json/40812665)